# How to add a pinpoint Image to a Map - Code provided

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to add an image in front of a Map Annotation pop up.

Here's an [image that will show you what exactly i want to do](http://www.xconomy.com/wordpress/wp-content/images/2009/06/sd_map-iphone.jpg). I need to add an image on the pin point as shown in the image.

```
AddMap *st = [[AddMap alloc] init];                 
                st.title = @"title";
                st.coordinate = region.center;                  
                [self.mapView addAnnotation:st];
```

How to add an image ?

note: AddMap is a class i wrote that initializes the `title` Variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do by setting an image to the property leftCalloutAccessoryView.

Try:

```
UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: ..........
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
```

Hope this helps.